# doctrine ManyToOne relation crashes symfony 3.3.1

Tags: postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-one

We have an old postgres 9.2 database with more than 400 tables. I used the symfony console to generate the entities, I created the repository classes that I need myself.

When I remove all relations from an entity, build a controller and repository to fetch some objects, everything works fine. But when I add a ManyToOne relation again symfony loads for about a minute or two and then I get a chrome error page "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". Maybe someone can help.

AppBundle\Entity\Firma.php (shortened for better visibility)

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Firma
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="firma", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="firma_fid_key", columns={"fid"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_2BED3563DF1BF902", columns={"ftypid"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_2BED35632453407B", columns={"hstraegerid"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_2BED356318F71675", columns={"hstypid"}), @ORM\Index(name="IDX_2BED3563950F9D92", columns={"uniid"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FirmaRepository")
 */
class Firma
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fid", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="firma_fid_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $fid;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Ftyp
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Ftyp")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ftypid", referencedColumnName="ftypid")
     */
    private $ftypid;
```

AppBundle\Repository\FirmaRepository.php

```
namespace AppBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class FirmaRepository extends EntityRepository
{

}
```

AppBundle\Entity\Ftyp.php (shortened for visibility)

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Ftyp
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ftyp")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FtypRepository")
 */
class Ftyp
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ftypid", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="ftyp_ftypid_seq", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $ftypid;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ftyp", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
     */
    private $ftyp;

}
```

Comment: Have you checked your (error) logs?

Comment: Sorry that I can only answer now. I restarted my pc and opened the symfony url again, now the page loads forever and nothing happens. I also don't see any error in the php error log.

Comment: It's strange... I always used return new Reponse(var_dump($firma)); to test my code. Now I used return new Response($firma->getFtypid()->getFtyp()); and it worked, I saw the string "Standard" as expected. ARGH! :D

Comment: `var_dump()` can crash your application because of a memory limit. Use VarDumper::dump() instead. That's the power of a framework like Symfony ;).

Comment: Thanks. I will do that! :)